# Give paragraph effect through CSS

Tags: css

How to give paragraph effect to my paragraph using CSS?

For example:

```
               This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. 
This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. 
This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. 
This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph.
This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. 
This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph.
This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph. This is my paragraph.
```

I'd like the padding like in the first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `text-indent` property.

```
p { text-indent: 1em; }
```

See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-indent

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
p:first-line { padding-left:10em; }
```

Comment: That doesn't always work. Plus, there is a css property just for this, no need to go all advanced.

Comment: Nice to have the alternative, thanks for posting, but yeah, not always work..